# Construct a Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, traversal

How can I construct a tree given its inorder and preorder traversal?
I am just looking for an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Well, recursively.  I hope you're not my student.

Comment: Would need some clarification. What is the format of the input data? Is the tree balanced? What do you mean by efficient (Ordo(x), or just "not horribly crazy"). What is the structure you want to build? Tree as linked objects, or tree using an array.

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/software-design-43/finding-binary-tree-from-inorder-and-preorder-traversals-151147.html

Comment: I am a graduate. So, nobody's student anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

A blatant copy and paste from [Sun's (Oracle now, I guess...) forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=426&threadID=667512):

> > **Question:** 
> >  *Can anybody help me on how to construct Binary tree from inorder and postorder traversals,i just want to know the algorithm so that i can apply it.*
>
> **Answer:**
>   Let `p_1`, `p_2` `...` `p_n` be the postorder traversal and let `i_1`, `i_2` `...` `i_n` be the inorder traversal. From the postorder traversal we know that the root of the tree is `p_n`. Find this element in the inorder traversal, say `i_1`, `i_2` `...` `i_k-1` `p_n` `i_k+1` `...` `i_n`. From the inorder traversal we find all the elements in the left subtree, i.e. `i_1`, `i_2` `...` `i_k-1` and in the right subtree, i.e. `i_k+1` `...` `i_n` respectively.
>
> Remove element `p_n` (and element `i_k` `==` `p_n`). Find the rightmost element `p_j` in `p_1`, `p_2` `...` `p_j` `...` `p_n-1` where `p_j` is an element in `i_1`, `i_2` ... `i_k-1`. This is the root of the left subtree of the original tree. 
>   Split `p_1`, `p_2` `...` `p_j` and `p_j+1` ... `p_n-1` and `i_1`, `i_2` `...` `i_k-1` and `i_k+1` `...` `i_n`. Now you have two subsequences representing the postorder and inorder traversal of the two subtrees of the original
>   tree.

Author: [JosAH](http://forums.sun.com/profile.jspa?userID=431408).

I've implemented the algorithm once following Jos' instructions, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: It is too time consuming to find rightmost element p_j in p_1 ~ p_n-1 while it is also in i_1~i_k-1. It takes O(n^2) time. 
 Actually, after removing p_n, and find its position in i_1~i_n. We already know the position of p_j. This is because we already know the count of nodes in its left and right subtree, which could be gotten by counting the elements after p_n in i_1~i_n. By this, we could easily find the place to split p_1~p_n-1

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I won't give you a full answer, but hopefully, enough to get you moving.

Imagine you have preorder traversal of, say [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Binary_tree.svg) tree.

The traversal gives you 2-7-2-6-5-11-5 ... etc.  Notice that the 5 is actually the right child of the root.

Obviously, you can't tell that from just looking at the numbers, so either you will be told about the structure of the tree, or you need to store some additional data (ie, whether the a node is the left child or right child, for example).

Parsing the tree is simply a recursive function that takes the preorder traversal as input (think about your scope when you are passing the input).  As I mentioned earlier, your preorder traversal should have some additional data attached.

---

Efficiency:

consider how many times each node is visited when you build this tree, but also consider the operation of reading the input.  Is there a way to reorganize the input faster than you can build the tree?  What structure would you have to use if you need to manipulate the data.

---

In Order:  You will need the same idea to get you through it, so I won't cover it.  I'm sure someone else will, if you are desperate for it.