# tree traversal from inorder and preorder

Tags: java, tree-traversal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Construct a Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184949/construct-a-tree)

Hi, how can I write a prorgam with java so as to create a tree with a given preorder and a inorder. I know to tree traversal with inorder and also tree traversal with preorder, but I can't do the same for creating tree from both inorder and preorder together

Comment: You need to clarify this a little bit. A tree will always have the same preorder or inorder. Are you trying to write a function that creates the tree given either traversal?

Comment: Example please. Preferably with an illustration.

Comment: for example I have the inorder={2,4,1,7,12,11} and preorder={1,2,4,7,11,12}, and now I want to create a tree with the above inorder and preorder

Comment: can you give an example or where it has both orders at once.  It sounds like what you need is two collections. one with the preorder and one with the inorder.

Comment: Is this probably some home work assignment???

Answer (score 1):

Let's learn by example:

PRE-ORDER:= a b d g h e i c f j
IN- ORDER:= g d h b e i a f j c

From Pre-order we can say that,

`a` is root.

From In-order we can say that,

`g d h b e i` are left sub-tree and `fjc` are right sub-tree,

now next root would be `b` (from pre-order)

and left and right sub-tree are `gdh` and `ei` from in-order...

continue doing this...

Comment: Do you have some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

algorithm is so so easy if you build your tree correctly!

```
preorder :

print(tree){
     printf(tree.value);
     print(tree.left);
     print(tree.right);
}

inorder :

print(tree) {
   print(tree.left);
   print(tree.value);
   print(tree.right);
}
```

more information is here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: You are not pointing out the answer..