# With pre-order and in-order traversal reconstruct binary search tree

Tags: search, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a function to reconstruct a binary search tree. I'm trying to do it by hand first.

Say i have:
pre- 10,3,5,4,15,7,8,2,9,20
in- 4,5,3,15,10,20,8,7,9,20

I can't figure it out. I know 10 has to be the root and that all the numbers to the left of 10 in the in-order sequence need to be in the right sub tree.

that would give me 4,5,3,15

15 is greater that 10 and to be a binary search tree all the nodes in the left sub-tree should be smaller than the root.

Does that mean that this two sequences form an invalid binary search tree?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I construct a tree given its inorder and preorder traversal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184949/construct-a-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Based on the in-order traversal you have been given, your tree does not seem to be a BST. 10 must be the root node, as you gleaned from looking at the first node in the pre-order traversal. Everything to the left of 10 in the in-order traversal should be in the left sub-tree, and everything to the right of 10 should be in the right sub-tree. As you have pointed out, it cannot be possible for 15 to be to the left of 10 (or 7, 8, and 9 to be to the right of 10). That being said, you could still reconstruct a tree from this data. It just doesn't have nodes in sorted order.